# Is there a way to display UI text from different languages in different corresponding fonts?

Tags: gnome, fonts

GUI, Terminal, etc.. There are many places where a multilingual user can encounter non-english text rendered horribly in their English font of choice (chosen in the Settings application). And picking a native font for those gives the user also-not-so-great English glyphs or worse unicode support (for emojis?)
Certain fonts look great for the glyphs of one language but degrade greatly for another. There's not a single font that looks great for all Japanese, Chinese, Korean, Hebrew, Arabic, Indic, ... glyphs.

So my question is simple: Is there a way to assign certain fonts to displaying certain languages (ranges of unicode indices(?)) in gnome? Is there a DE-agnostic way? Is there anything like that at all even?

Comment: is this clearer?

Comment: @Gunnar forgot to tag you

Comment: Well... I'm not aware of a way to do exactly what you ask for. OTOH I think that the possible conflicts you talk about can often be dealt with in other ways. For instance, `fonts-noto-cjk` is installed by default on every Ubuntu machine. That package provides nice rendering of Japanese, Korean as well as Chinese without affecting the rendering of non-CJK glyphs. If there is a real conflict, it may be handled with a fontconfig config file. It would make it much easier to help if you could provide one or two examples of conflicts you have encountered.